# Index of class group in the narrow class group

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a totally real number field. Can anybody please give me a reference for the fact that
$$
[\text{Cl}^+(F): \text{Cl}(F)]=[\mathcal O_F^{\times, +}: (\mathcal O_F^{\times})^2], 
$$
where $\text{Cl}^+(F)$ is the narrow class group of $F$, $\text{Cl}(F)$ is the class group of $F$,   $\mathcal O_F^{\times, +}$ is the group of totally positive units, and $(\mathcal O_F^{\times})^2$ is the subgroup of $\mathcal O_F^{\times}$ consisting of the squares?

Comment: $\operatorname{Cl}(F)$ is a quotient of $\operatorname{Cl}^+(F)$. By $[\operatorname{Cl}^+(F):\operatorname{Cl}(F)]$ do you simply mean the quotient of the group's orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof: First note that $|\!\operatorname{Cl}^+(F)|/|\!\operatorname{Cl}(F)|=|\!P_F/P_F^+|$ where $P_F$ is the set of principal fractional ideals and $P_K^+$ is the set of fractional ideals generated by a totally positive element. From the short exact sequence $$1\to \frac{{\mathcal O}_F^\times}{{\mathcal O}_F^{\times, +}}\to\frac{F^\times}{F^{\times, +}}\to \frac{P_F}{P_F^+}\to 1$$
(where $F^{\times,+}$ denotes the set of totally positive elements in $F^\times$) we get $|\!P_F/P_F^+| = \frac{|{\mathcal O}_F^\times/{\mathcal O}_F^{\times,+}|}{|F^\times/F^{\times, +}|}$. Now ${\mathcal O}_F^\times/({\mathcal O}_F^{\times})^2\cong C_2^n$ by Dirichlet's unit theorem and $F^\times/F^{\times, +}\cong C_2^n$ (essentially by the approximation theorem). Here $n=[F:\Bbb Q]$. For both isomorphisms we use that $F$ is totally real. The result follows from this. As a reference see e.g. Lang's Algebraic Number Theory, the section on generalized ideal class groups, in particular Theorem 1 on p. 127. The only thing not done there for this case is comparing this with $({\mathcal O}_F^\times)^2$ but as seen above this is a quick argument using the Dirichlet unit theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please explain a little bit more about the approximation theorem?

Comment: Consider the map $F^\times \to \{\pm1\}^n$ given by $x\mapsto (\operatorname{sign}\sigma_i(x))_i$ where the $\sigma_i$ are the embeddings. By definition, $F^{\times,+}$ is the kernel of this map. The approximation theorem implies that the map is surjective: Given any configuration of signs, we can find an element which has these signs under the corresponding embeddings.